Permission denied when running docker-compose in a mounted drive. Please help
I have an issue with docker deploying from mounted drive.
Here is the server setup details:
Ubuntu 24.04 LTS
OUTPUT OF lsblk:
sda                            8:0    0    900G   0   disk
├─sda1                         8:1    0      1M   0   part
├─sda2                         8:2    0      2G   0   part  /boot
├─sda3                         8:3    0  105.1G   0   part
│ └─ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv      252:0  0  105.1G   0   lvm   /
└─sda5                         8:5    0  779.2G   0   part  /mnt/partition2

I am using snap docker and don't know in depth knowledge of how it is setup but all my docker apps are inside my home directory and works all fine ( /home/USER/dockerapps/.... ). I use docker-compose.yml files for all the apps and it works all fine. Now for some of the apps that uses more storage space, I wanted to use another disk and use that path to deploy docker using docker compose up -d --build or docker compose up -d  and I used to get an error i.e.
open /mnt/partition2/dockerstacks/MYAPPS/docker-compose.yml: permission denied
Then I saw some post about resolving it by giving permission to the folder and atleast group permission so the USER can execute the docker command there. That is why I added permission to USER. I have a lot of other APPS already in the dockerstacks  so I cannot use change permission to all the files and folder inside it like chown -R USER:USER nor chmod 775 -R .  I have manually set permission for each folder with -R recursive with parent as ROOT:USER permission and inside ones as USER:USER. But now I am getting this error:
open /mnt/partition2/dockerstacks/MYAPPS/.env: permission denied
OUTPUT  of ls -al of all the folders
 $ ls -al   /mnt/partition2
total 12
drwxrwxr-x  3 root USER  4096   Aug  7 19:36 .
drwxr-xr-x  5 root root  4096   Aug  7 19:11 ..
drwxrwxr-x 10 root USER  4096   Aug 26 19:42 dockerstacks

$ ls -al /mnt/partition2/dockerstacks/
total 40
drwxrwxr-x 10 root   USER    4096 Aug 26 19:42  .
drwxrwxr-x  3 root   USER    4096 Aug  7 19:36  ..
drwxrwxr-x  3 root   root    4096 Jul 16 23:47  MYAPPS

$ ls -al  /mnt/partition2/dockerstacks/MYAPPS
total 288
drwxrwxr-x 6 USER USER  4096  Sep  4 13:08 .
drwxrwxr-x 3 USER USER  4096  Sep  4 12:51 ..
drwxrwxr-x 8 USER USER  4096  Sep  4 12:55 app
drwxrwxr-x 2 USER USER  4096  Sep  4 12:55 builder
-rw-rw-r-- 1 USER USER  1209  Sep  4 13:08 docker-compose.yml
-rw-rw-r-- 1 USER USER    41  Sep  4 12:58 .env
drwxrwxr-x 8 USER USER  4096  Sep  4 12:55 .git

This is my entry to the /etc/fstab
/dev/disk/by-id/dm-uuid-LVM-TTTTTT  /                 ext4   defaults     0       
/dev/disk/by-uuid/6d2a0a8bTTTTTTT   /boot             ext4   defaults     0  1
/swap.img       none    swap    sw  0       0
UUID=ede5340a-17d4-TTTTTTTTTTT      /mnt/partition2   ext4   defaults     0  2

Thank you very much. Also any suggestion is welcome and much appreciated.

Double check that 'defaults' does what you think it does in/etc/fstab. Both rw behaviour and execution can be controlled from here

This is a comment not an answer.

There is other option that works
